# NSAttributedString '\n' ignored

Tags: ios, ios6, uitextview, nsattributedstring, end-of-line

I have a single view whose only UI element is a `UITextView`. In `viewDidLoad:` I create an attributed string with "Text\n" and set the text view's attributed text as such:

```
NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Text\n"];  
[self.textView setAttributedText:string];
```

My problem is that the line break is ignored when I run the app.

If I use an `NSString` and `setText:` that doesn't happen.

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Text\n"];  
[self.textView setText:string];
```

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening? I can't seem to find anything in documentation or otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *cr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"\n"];
```

So if you have two NSMutableAttributedString (string1 and string2) you can do:

```
[string1 appendAttributedString: cr];
[string1 appendAttributedString: string2];
```

It's horrible and not elegant.... but it works!!!

Comment: `NSAttributedString` can not use `appendAttributedString` because it can not be changed. Is it correct use `NSMutableAttributedString`?

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you to use:

```
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:[@"Text<BR />" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] documentAttributes:NULL];
```

I use this all the time and it works perfectly. I even made a macro out of it:

```
#define html2AttributedString(htmlString)                                                                   \
    [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:[(htmlString) dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]         \
    documentAttributes:NULL] autorelease]
```

And then, you can make macro for color, alignment, font, etc…

In short, you just need to replace all the `"\n"` in your string with `<BR />` and use the code provided above. For the replacement part, use:

```
[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:... withString:…];
```

For iOS, you can check out [this page](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/uiwebview-must-die/) in which they give you a replacement.

> Our initWithHTML methods aim to perfectly match the output from the
>   Mac version. This is possible to achieve for characters and I have
>   unit tests in place that make certain this keeps being perfect.
>   Regarding the attributes there are many things that have to be done
>   slightly different on iOS to achieve the same look. I won’t bother you
>   with the details there.

Comment: The ‘initWithHTML:‘ method isn't available in iOS.

Comment: At this point I'm more concerned with understanding why I'm not getting the expected behavior but I'll keep this in mind if I end up having to work around it.

Comment: @winsome Then, you can check on the side of: the paragraph configuration of your attributed string, or on the configuration of your UITextView. Check the page 29 and after of this document http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/strings/strings.pdf

Comment: Brilliant! This should be the selected answer.